# Dependent names template question from Stroustrup example

Tags: c++, c++11

Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 748 has an example of *dependent names* with regards to member templates.  Does anyone know what the dependent name is in this example?  Is it `all` based on the template parameter `Alloc`?

Thanks!

```
class Pool { 
public:
    template<typename T>
    T∗ get();
    template<typename T>
    void release(T∗); 
};

template<typename Alloc>
void f(Alloc& all)
{
    int∗ p1 = all.get<int>();
    int∗ p2 = all.template get<int>();
}

void user(Pool& pool)
{ 
    f(pool);
}
```

Also Stroustrup states that "Compared to the use of typename to explicitly state that a name is assumed to name a type, the use of template to explicitly state that a name is assumed to name a template is rare.".  Curious, why would this example be so rare?

Comment: `get` is a dependent name. Before `Alloc` is known, the compiler can't even tell whether `all.get` refers to a template, and whether the `<` that follows is supposed to be parsed as part of template-id, or a less-than operator. That's why `template` keyword is needed; `<` is taken as a less-than operator without it.

Comment: It's rare because you're usually not invoking a template method on a template type parameter.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik are there not multiple dependent names? His example on p747 claims that.

Comment: I only see one in the example shown. I don't have the book.

Comment: @igortandetnik If I define a non-template member function `int* get() {return &t;}` and call it as above `int* p2 = all.get();` it works.  Isn't get still a dependent name here?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What the name `get` a dependent on?

Comment: `get` is dependent on the template parameter. Maybe it's a member function; maybe it's a data member of class type with overloaded `operator()`; no way to tell until the template is instantiated with a particular argument. And yes, in `all.get()` it's still a dependent name - it's just that, when it's not followed by `<`, there is no ambiguity in the syntax, so the compiler doesn't need any additional hints.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik.  That helped clear up some significant confusion on my side!  thanks!